# Generic Repository with an Id of different types

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a generic Repository like this which allows Id to be off different types (TKey)

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class
{
  Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(TKey id);
  Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ListAllAsync();
  Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ListAsync(string criteriaName, DynamicParameters parameters);
  Task<TEntity> CreateAsync(TEntity entity);
  Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity);
  Task DeleteAsync(TKey id);
}
```

How do I inject this in .net core 2 services? I see examples like this

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

which works find if I remove TKey and fix the Id to an INT. But I want the Id to be flexible. i.e sometimes it's a guid or an int. I could make the Id type of string but that feels lazy and wrong!

Comment: You could remove the generics definition from the interface which would allow you to call the methods with any `TEntity` and `TKey` (or even deduce `TKey` from the entity).

Comment: Deduce the Key from the Entity?  I would like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));
```

This is what worked for me.